# CSCore - Play audio from a FileStream or MemoryStream

Tags: audio, cscore

Using CSCore, how can I play WMA or MP3 from a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` (unlike using a method that take a `string` for a file path or url).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the `GetCodec(Stream stream, object key)`-overload of the `CodecFactory`-class is internal, you could simply perform the same steps manually and directly choose your decoder. Acutally, `CodeFactory` is just a helper class for determining the decoders automatically, so if you already know about your codec, you can do this yourself.
Internally, when passing a file path, CSCore checks the file extension and then opens up a `FileStream` (using `File.OpenRead`) that is handled over to the chosen decoder.

All you need to do, is using the specific decoder for your codec.

For MP3, you could use the [DmoMP3Decoder](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/Codecs/MP3/DmoMP3Decoder.cs) which inherits from [DmoStream](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/DMO/DmoStream.cs) that implements the [IWaveSource](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/c4572d5b915d8b384a01a627b826076a35d1491c/CSCore/IWaveSource.cs)-interface you need to handle over as sound source.

Here is an adjusted sample from the docs on [Codeplex](http://cscore.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Play%20a%20sound&referringTitle=Documentation):

```cs
public void PlayASound(Stream stream)
{
    //Contains the sound to play
    using (IWaveSource soundSource = GetSoundSource(stream))
    {
        //SoundOut implementation which plays the sound
        using (ISoundOut soundOut = GetSoundOut())
        {
            //Tell the SoundOut which sound it has to play
            soundOut.Initialize(soundSource);
            //Play the sound
            soundOut.Play();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //Stop the playback
            soundOut.Stop();
        }
    }
}

private ISoundOut GetSoundOut()
{
    if (WasapiOut.IsSupportedOnCurrentPlatform)
        return new WasapiOut();
    else
        return new DirectSoundOut();
}

private IWaveSource GetSoundSource(Stream stream)
{
    // Instead of using the CodecFactory as helper, you specify the decoder directly:
    return new DmoMp3Decoder(stream);

}
```

For WMA, you can use the [WmaDecoder](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/Codecs/WMA/WMADecoder.cs). 
You should check the implementation of the different decoders: https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/Codecs/CodecFactory.cs#L30

Make sure, that no exceptions are thrown and handle them with the usage of another decoder ([Mp3MediafoundationDecoder](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/c4572d5b915d8b384a01a627b826076a35d1491c/CSCore/Codecs/MP3/MP3MediafoundationDecoder.cs)) as in the linked source code. Also don't forget to dispose your stream in the end.